# Python, Tkinter, Can not access StringVar() Object

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

with the attached code i try to access the StringVar object in the widget object himself.

But unfortunately  it says 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set''
Any idea why? Thanks in advance..

```
import Tkinter as tk

class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.fieldList = {}

        f = tk.Entry(self.master, text='', width = 7)
        f.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.addToFieldList(f, 'MyFieldA')

    def addToFieldList(self, fieldObj, fieldId):
        fieldObj.bind('<Return>', lambda event, temp=fieldObj :self.commitField(event, temp))

        t = tk.StringVar()  
        fieldObj['textvariable'] = t
        setattr(fieldObj, 'fieldId', fieldId)
        self.fieldList[fieldId] = fieldObj


    def commitField(self, event, sender):
        newValue = sender.get()
        t = sender['textvariable']
        t.set('newValue')  # here comes the error

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = mainWindow(root)

    root.wm_geometry("500x180")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please do your own research before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Put self in front of the StringVar which will let you call it without an error. This is because it is not a global variable and so the function cannot access it. Also change `t = sender['textvariable']` to `sender['textvariable'] = t`.